# Is there an event triggered when we navigate from one cell to another in edit mode - ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have been using Ag grid community and enterprise editions - version 21. I have a use-case where I need to call an api each time a cell's value changes. I know that onCellValueChanged event would be triggered after editing is complete in each cell in case of single cell edit mode. But I am using full row edit mode. So, in my case onCellValueChanged event would be triggered at the end of row editing for all the columns altogether. But I am looking for an event which would be called after each cell has been edited and when we navigate to the next cell. I searched the ag grid docs and couldn't find any such event. Not sure if I am missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to do that. I'm afraid you have to write your own cell editor and listen to the focus in/focus out events yourself so you'd know when the switching happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you assume the user would move to the next/previous cells by using shortcuts. Default shortcuts to jump between cells are `Tab` and `Shift`+`Tab`. So the implementation is to listen to the `onCellKeyDown` event to know when the user jumps between editor cells, and call the API with the updated value

```js
<AgGridReact
  editType="fullRow"
  onCellKeyDown={(e) => {
    const TAB_KEY = 9;
    const getValue = () =>
      e.api
        .getCellEditorInstances({ rowNodes: [e.node] })
        .map((instance) => instance.eInput.value);

    if (e.event.shiftKey) {
      if (e.event.keyCode === TAB_KEY) {
        console.log("Jump to previous editor");
        console.log(getValue());
      }
    } else if (e.event.keyCode === TAB_KEY) {
      console.log("Jump to next editor");
      console.log(getValue());
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Example

Open the console to see the changes

[image: Edit AgGrid Switch Editor Event]